# Determine if process is system relevant

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I have a `HANDLE` to a process and would like to know if the process is system relevant, like the taskmanager does in the image below.

[image]

If I try to close such a process though the taskmanager, it asks me to either shutdown the whole computer or cancel. *(I have not found anything related to this)*

Comment: Those are system processes

Comment: You can replicate the behavior via NtSetInformationProcess via the BreakOnTermination flag; the RtlSetProcessIsCritical routine internally calls NtSetInformationProcess. Bear in mind that RtlSetProcessIsCritical really is situated in NTDLL, whereas NtSetInformationProcess truly belongs in kernel-mode memory under NTOSKRNL (Windows Kernel), so the NTDLL export for it will just perform a system call.

Comment: The Windows Kernel has internal, undocumented and opaque structures which it uses to track things such as critical states. As an example, look into research on _EPROCESS, _KPROCESS, _ETHREAD and _KTHREAD to learn more about the fields they have and thus what type of data will be tracked in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'insider' term for such processes is "critical processes" - that is to say, processes that Windows needs to have running at all times in order to function properly.  A good example is the process that manages the logon screen (WinLogon) - can't do much without that.

[Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) wrote a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035) about this recently.  Amongst other things, he had this to say:

1. [IsProcessCritical()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn386160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) determines whether the specified process is considered critical.
2. In addition to these, Task Manager also keeps a hard-coded list of processes that it puts in the "Windows processes" list whenever it sees them, for example Console Window Host (which hosts the window(s) for running console apps) and Desktop Window Manager.

I've no idea how you would get hold of the contents of that list.

Raymond goes into more detail about what a critical process actually *is* in his blog.  Try terminating one in the 'Details' tab, if you want to bluescreen your computer.

Comment: Before Windows 8, the IsProcessCritical() routine will not be available (it wasn't implemented back then), and thus for Windows 7 or below, you'd have to use the NtQueryInformationProcess routine (NTDLL exports a routine for it which will perform a system call) to check the value for the BreakOnTermination flag. Also, as a side note, you can also check if a specific thread is "critical" or not through NtQueryInformationThread (also checking the BreakOnTermination flag). You can still terminate a critical process if you remove the set on the BreakOnTermination flag.

Comment: Although if you were to terminate a critical process without getting the BSOD invoked by doing that, the system will not work properly depending on what you targeted. Anyway, in layman's terms, a critical process is one where one where if it becomes terminated whilst with the critical state set on it, the Windows Kernel will invoke KeBugCheckEx and force a BSOD crash.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @Theodore Tsirpanis